# python os path join on windows shows unexpected behavior

Tags: python, path, os.path

I looked at a few examples and docs but I can't explain below behavior of `os.path.join()` on Windows.

```
import os

os.path.isdir(os.path.join("C:", "\\", "Users\\Public"))
Out[3]: True

os.path.isdir(os.path.join("C:\\Users", "\\", "Public"))
Out[4]: False
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this?  `print(os.path.join("C:\\Users", "\\", "Public"))`, for example.

Comment: interesting, this returns `C:\Public`

Comment: this returns `True`as well `os.path.isdir(os.path.join("C:\\Users", "Public"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any part of a path starting with a "\" is considered an absolute path. So the first example works because there is no relative path before the "\" but the second example fails.

Comment: strange behavior. then the function is useless for my purpose.

Comment: Why? The second example will work if you just leave out the "\" after "users".

Comment: I try but I have to build the paths programmatically sometimes with drive letter and sometimes without. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally developed on windows, but I don't think you're supposed to give the '\' in the parameter list.

i.e.: try:
`os.path.isdir(os.path.join("C:", "Users", "Public"))`

Comment: The output of your version is `False`. I have seen a number of code snippets explicitly putting in the escaped backslash or at least the `os.sep`.